# UI Error while calling app script functions through app script API

Tags: api, google-apps-script, custom-function

I have written functions in the app script bound to a google sheet that validates sheet data and shows a pop up in the sheet when there is an error.

Now, I am calling same functions form API calls in a Node js application to return a validation response without interacting google sheet.

API calls are successful, function gets called but unable to initialize UI.
I just don't want to write duplicate functions for same purpose but without accessing UI.

I get an error that says **Script error message: Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.**

How do I solve this issue by retaining the UI calling functionality of the app script functions and also getting work done through API?

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the call in a try catch block.

```
try {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
} catch (f) {
  // do nothing here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Amit Agarwal, This trick works for me!